# mysql returning incorect string ...

Tags: mysql

Hy ... i'm trying to group_concat the primary key (`id`) like this : `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT (id) AS idz FROM table_name GROUP BY group;` but the result is `[BLOB - 5 Bytes]` instead of `12,13,16,22`.

Why ?

Thank you

Comment: This passage from the Mysql manual might shed some light: "The result type is TEXT or BLOB unless group_concat_max_len is less than or equal to 512, in which case the result type is VARCHAR or VARBINARY." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT group_concat(cast(id as char) SEPARATOR ',') as idz
FROM table_name
GROUP BY `group`
```

Comment: Cast forces the integers in id into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here.

according to the group by documentation The return value is a nonbinary or binary string, depending on whether the arguments are nonbinary or binary strings. The result type is TEXT or BLOB

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

It may be that you're result is best represented as a BLOB.